# How to ingest JSON files into database? JSONLoader

Tags: json, langchain

https://python.langchain.com/docs/modules/data_connection/document_loaders/json

https://python.langchain.com/docs/modules/data_connection/document_transformers/recursive_json_splitter

That two links can't teach how to split json file.

```
loader = JSONLoader(file_path=file_path, jq_schema=".", text_content=False)
docs = loader.load()
            
print("docs: ")
pprint(docs)

splitter = RecursiveJsonSplitter(max_chunk_size=300)
chunks = splitter.split_json(json_data=docs, convert_lists=True)
```

TypeError: Object of type Document is not JSON serializable

Answer (score 0):

To have a quick demo I manually modify it simply if the content of your json file like this: https://python.langchain.com/docs/modules/data_connection/document_loaders/json

```
{'image': {'creation_timestamp': 1675549016, 'uri': 'image_of_the_chat.jpg'},
     'is_still_participant': True,
     'joinable_mode': {'link': '', 'mode': 1},
     'magic_words': [],
     'messages': [{'content': 'Bye!',
                   'sender_name': 'User 2',
                   'timestamp_ms': 1675597571851},
                  {'content': 'Oh no worries! Bye',
                   'sender_name': 'User 1',
                   'timestamp_ms': 1675597435669},
                  {'content': 'No Im sorry it was my mistake, the blue one is not '
                              'for sale',
                   'sender_name': 'User 2',
                   'timestamp_ms': 1675596277579},
                  {'content': 'I thought you were selling the blue one!',
                   'sender_name': 'User 1',
                   'timestamp_ms': 1675595140251},
                  {'content': 'Im not interested in this bag. Im interested in the '
                              'blue one!',
                   'sender_name': 'User 1',
                   'timestamp_ms': 1675595109305},
                  {'content': 'Here is $129',
                   'sender_name': 'User 2',
                   'timestamp_ms': 1675595068468},
                  {'photos': [{'creation_timestamp': 1675595059,
                               'uri': 'url_of_some_picture.jpg'}],
                   'sender_name': 'User 2',
                   'timestamp_ms': 1675595060730},
                  {'content': 'Online is at least $100',
                   'sender_name': 'User 2',
                   'timestamp_ms': 1675595045152},
                  {'content': 'How much do you want?',
                   'sender_name': 'User 1',
                   'timestamp_ms': 1675594799696},
                  {'content': 'Goodmorning! $50 is too low.',
                   'sender_name': 'User 2',
                   'timestamp_ms': 1675577876645},
                  {'content': 'Hi! Im interested in your bag. Im offering $50. Let '
                              'me know if you are interested. Thanks!',
                   'sender_name': 'User 1',
                   'timestamp_ms': 1675549022673}],
     'participants': [{'name': 'User 1'}, {'name': 'User 2'}],
     'thread_path': 'inbox/User 1 and User 2 chat',
     'title': 'User 1 and User 2 chat'}
```

A workaround sample that maybe not a final solution:
You can try to use **RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter** to handle the docs from JSONLoader. Then AI can understand the content.

```
loader = JSONLoader(file_path=file_path, jq_schema=".messages[]", text_content=False)
docs = loader.load()
            
print("docs: ")
pprint(docs)

splitter = RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter(chunk_size=500, chunk_overlap=50)
chunks = splitter.split_documents(docs)
```